# Updating many-to-many relations in Prisma

Tags: prisma

[image]

I have a group of checkboxes for skin concerns. Users can check/uncheck them before submitting, which means the set of skin concerns submitted can be different every time.

I modeled it in Prisma schema as an 'explicit' many-to-many relation.

```
model User {
  id                 String                 @id @default(cuid())
  name               String?
  nickname           String?                @unique
  ...
  skinConcerns       SkinConcernsForUsers[]
  ...
}

model SkinConcern {
  id   Int                    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String                 @unique
  user SkinConcernsForUsers[]
}

model SkinConcernsForUsers {
  user          User        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        String
  skinConcern   SkinConcern @relation(fields: [skinConcernId], references: [id])
  skinConcernId Int

  @@id([userId, skinConcernId])
}
```

Then, SkinConcerns table is seeded with the following values, using `prisma.skinConcern.createMany`:

```
"ACNE",
"DRYNESS",
"OILY_SKIN",
"PIGMENTATION",
"REDNESS",
"WRINKLES",
```

`SkinConcerns` in Update mutation input comes in the form of array of strings, e.g. `["PIGMENTATION", "REDNESS"]`.

I want to update the skin concerns for users (`SkinConcernsForUsers`) from the `prisma.user.update` query, but it's tricky, since I'm not merely creating SkinConcerns, but have to connect to existing set of skin concerns.

I've tried directly `set`ting `skinConcerns` in `user`, like

```
await prisma.user.update({
  where: { nickname },
  data: {
    // ... other user data
    skinConcerns: {
      set: [
        {
          skinConcern: {
            connect: { name: "PIGMENTATION" },
          },
        },
        {
          skinConcern: {
            connect: { name: "REDNESS" },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    // ... other user data
  }
});
```

among many other things, but of course this is not a correct argument and fails with error

```
Unknown arg `connect` in data.skinConcerns.update.0.where.connect for type SkinConcernsForUsersWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `select`?
Argument data for data.skinConcerns.update.0.data is missing.
Unknown arg `connect` in data.skinConcerns.update.1.where.connect for type SkinConcernsForUsersWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `select`?
Argument data for data.skinConcerns.update.1.data is missing.
```

Is there a way to do this? Is it even possible to update this in `prisma.user.update`?

I guess I could directly update `SkinConcernsForUsers`. In that case, should I just delete all rows associated to the user that are not in the user input `["PIGMENTATION", "REDNESS"]`, then create rows that don't already exist? What will it look like in prisma code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would change your schema for `SkinConcern`. The `id` field is not necessary and will create complications in queries (you would needlessly need to map each `name` to `id` when trying to connect/disconnect records.

The `name` field is sufficient as the primary key, as it is always unique for a certain record.

The changed schema looks like this

```
model SkinConcern {
  name String                  @id    // name is the new @id. 
  user SkinConcernsForUsers[]
}

model SkinConcernsForUsers {
  user          User        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        String
  skinConcern   SkinConcern @relation(fields: [skinConcernName], references: [name])
  skinConcernName String

  @@id([userId, skinConcernName])
}
```

The query you want to do can be executed in two steps with the `SkinConcernsForUsers` model.

1. **Step 1:**  Remove existing `SkinConcernsForUsers` records a user is connected to. These are no longer relevant, as you want to overwrite the previous selection.
2. **Step 2:** Create new `SkinConcernsForUsers` records with the new choices.

Here is what the code looks like

```js
// step 1
await prisma.skinConcernsForUsers.deleteMany({
    where: {
        userId: "1",
    },
});

// step 2
await prisma.skinConcernsForUsers.createMany({
    data: [
        {
            userId: "1",
            skinConcernName: "REDNESS",
        },
        {
            userId: "1",
            skinConcernName: "PIGMENTATION",
        },
    ],
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, this is the approach that occurred to me right after asking this question, and I did some research about using strings as the primary key. The general advice on SO is to use auto-incrementing integer IDs. I think in my case performance isn't much of an issue, but I'm worried it'll be a lot of headache if I have to change these keys in the future (although I don't think that's likely). Anyways, it will make my job much much simpler so probably better to save some headaches now than to worry about potential headache in the future.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: By the way, for another table, if I absolutely have to have an integer ID as the primary key and a separate name column (as in my original question), how should I solve this?

Comment: You would need to have some kind of mapping to `name_column` -> `intenger_ID`. Using this mapping, you find the `integer_ID` for a corresponding `name_column` (Let's say REDNESS maps to ID 3). Then, you change up the queries to use the `integer_ID` field in place of the `name_column`  (For the example query I wrote, you would change `skinConcernName` to `skinConcernId`).

Comment: How you plan to store the `name_column` -> `intenger_ID` mapping is up to you. If the number of records is very small, you could just keep them as a dictionary/object/map in your application code. If there are lots of records (Let's say there are hundreds/thousands of skin concerns), then you would have to run another query to the database to fetch all of these (a bit inefficient).

Comment: Thanks. What I'm most worried about in that case is data inconsistency between the database and the code. What do you do to ensure they're always synced up?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you write it in the code manually, there's no real way to "guarantee" synchronization. I would consider writing a small test suite to verify that the data is synced up with the database. But as I said before, this would be very unmanagable if the number of records is too high, in such case I would just query the database with the unique `name_column` to find the matching `integer_ID` primary key column.

Comment: dont forget to use transaction for these 2 steps ;)